# Web application failed to start

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, web-applications

My application failed to start with a strange error. What does it mean?

```
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:new_prog_22' did not find a matching property.
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.65
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 9 2015 08:36:58 UTC
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.65.0
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows XP
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            5.1
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_66-b18
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\spring_new_works\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\spring_new_works\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\spring_new_works\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65\endorsed
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/jre/lib/i386;C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;;C:\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 623 ms
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
янв 11, 2016 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.65
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [C:\spring_new_works\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\new_prog_22\]
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20:47:06,375  INFO ContextLoader:285 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
20:47:06,515  INFO AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:513 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jan 11 20:47:06 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
20:47:06,609  INFO AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:240 - No annotated classes found for specified class/package [control.SpringConfig]
20:47:06,687  INFO ContextLoader:325 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 312 ms
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter CacheControl
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: filters.CacheControlFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4841)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5535)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter GzipFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: util.gzip.GZipServletFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4841)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5535)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/new_prog_22] startup failed due to previous errors
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20:47:06,703  INFO AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:873 - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jan 11 20:47:06 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Shutting down log4j
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
янв 11, 2016 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1882 ms
```

Note the WARNING message in the beggining of the logs. The application really names `new_prog_22` and the same name is in pom.xml. Also the filter classes are present. How to fix it?

Comment: The filters aren't present else the server would be able to load them. Either add the jar that contains them as a dependency or make sure the filters get compiled and added to the war correctly.

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml`? perhaps your filter dependencies are in compile or test scope and thus not included in final war. If this is not the case, Did you check if the resulting `war` includes that libraries inside `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: @malaguna the pom.xm does not contain any scopes with `compile` or `test`. The dependencies of those filters is `javax.servlet.` and that dependecie is not present in `pom` but instead the server runtime is present in the build path.

Comment: @M.Deinum I finally started it as war file on different server, but I still cat start it under the eclipse...

Comment: @rozero if you don't manage that dependencies in maven, but they are present in server runtime, Has you eclipse server environments installed the same libraries? or, Do you have configured **Java Build Path** for the eclipse project in Eclipse?

Comment: @malaguna be shure, it configured.  I finally solved it. the problem was in eclipse workspase. new workspace was created and all packages and classes were moved to the new project and that solved the issue.